# How can I push multiple date and time objects to an array (PHP)?

Tags: php

I have a form where users are able to add multiple dates with their available times.  My question is how can I grab each set of date and times and push them into there own objects and then push them into an array that will be passed to the db? Each object will contain: date, start time, & end time.  There could be 1 set of these or more.

```
<div id="Times">
    <div class="TimeDetails">
        <div class="Day">
            <label for="day">Day</label>
            <input id="day" type="date" name="day"><i class="material-icons md-18 grey-text">event</i>
        </div>
        <div class="Start">
                <label for="start">Start</label>
                <input id="start" type="time" name="start"><i class="material-icons md-18 grey-text">query_builder</i>
        </div>
        <div class="End">
            <label for="end">End</label>
            <input id="end" type="time" name="end"><i class="material-icons md-18 grey-text">query_builder</i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `array_push` or `array[]` syntax is for adding item to an array.

Comment: @u_mulder do I need to do a foreach loop somehow in order to ensure that all of the inputted options are added to the array in the correct object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you setup the names of the inputs with array indexes that match like:

```
name="data[0][day]"
name="data[0][start]"
name="data[0][end]"

name="data[1][day]"
name="data[1][start]"
name="data[1][end]"

etc...
```

Then loop and build an array of objects:

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $data) {
    $objects[] = (object)$data;
}
```

You could also use this structure (though I prefer the first):

```
name="day[]"
name="start[]"
name="end[]"

name="day[]"
name="start[]"
name="end[]"

etc...
```

Then loop and build an array of objects:

```
foreach($_POST['day'] as $key => $day) {
    $objects[] = (object)array('day'   => $day,
                               'start' => $_POST['start'][$key],
                               'end'   => $_POST['end'][$key]);
}
```

Comment: How would I convert this into UTC format ending up with a start and end time?

Comment: Can you post as a new question with more detail on the current format and the result please?

Answer (score 1):

Can't be certain I understand what you're asking. But from my understanding this is what you'll want.

```html
<div id="showingTimes">
<div class="showingTimeDetails">
    <div class="<?php echo $widget_class; ?>--showingDay">
        <label class="requestShowingLabel" for="showing_day">Day</label>
        <input id="day" type="date" name="showing_day[]"><i class="material-icons md-18 grey-text">event</i>
    </div>
    <div class="<?php echo $widget_class; ?>--availableStart">
            <label class="requestShowingLabel" for="available_start">Available Start</label>
            <input id="available_start" type="time" name="available_start[]"><i class="material-icons md-18 grey-text">query_builder</i>
    </div>
    <div class="<?php echo $widget_class; ?>--availableEnd">
        <label class="requestShowingLabel" for="available_end">Available End</label>
        <input id="available_end" type="time" name="available_end[]"><i class="material-icons md-18 grey-text">query_builder</i>
    </div>
</div>
```

```php
$timeObjects = [];
for ($i = count($_POST['showing_day']); $i++) {
    $timeObject[$i] = new TimeObject();
    $timeObject[$i]->Day = $_POST['showing_day'][$i];
    $timeObject[$i]->AvailableStart = $_POST['available_start'][$i];
    $timeObject[$i]->AvailableEnd = $_POST['available_end'][$i];
}

var_dump($timeObjects);
```

Notice the name of the HTML input elements are now appended with "[]" implying that they are passed as an array.